# Posting to text file using AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

How do you post this AJAX request to a text file? The url it is posting to is something along the lines of submit.php, but I can't seem to figure out how to save it properly to a file named "data.txt"

```
function makeAjaxRequest(cData) {
    var promise = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: cData,
        dataType: 'json',
        async: true
    });

    promise.done(successFunction);
    promise.fail(errorFunction);
    promise.always(alwaysFunction);
}
```

The data itself is already fo the format using `data = JSON.stringify(collectedData);` in a previous statement.

EDIT: I guess the wording I used is poor, sorry. I intend to pass the data into submit.php using the POST method. I would like that submit.php file to concat the text to a text file.

Currently the submit.php file contains the following:

```
<?php  file_put_contents('mydata.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX); ?>
```

Comment: Can you show us the php code?

Comment: Do you mean you want to write to that file on the server? That would have to be handled in submit.php's code. (You could also configure .htaccess to process ".txt" URLs differently, but I'm not sure that's your intent)

Comment: you don't "post to a text file". You post to a server-side script which takes the POST input data and writes it to your file.

Comment: @MarcB I am posting it to the submit.php file while handles it, putting the text into a text file, I am not going directly from ajax to txt.

Comment: @Rik_S the one of submit.php?
<?php
file_put_contents('mydata.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
?>

Comment: @bitz: then you should say so. You don't show your actual url, you don't show your php code, you just say "post to a text file".

Comment: @MarcB but I did say "The url it is posting to is something along the lines of submit.php". I guess my wording was poor; sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didnt see how you retrieved the ajax data, since `$data` is undefined in your code, try this:

```
<?php  
    $data = file_get_contents('php://input');
    file_put_contents('mydata.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX); 
?>
```

This will write json strings to `mydata.txt`

Comment: Note he's using POST, not PUT

Comment: the *encoded* post values (which can be particularly ugly if using multipart/form-data, and are not pretty even with the "standard" encoding)

Comment: @Qualcuno the content type would be json not post encoded values since OP used `JSON.stringify()`

Comment: And then jQuery wraps it around some kind of encoding

Comment: really ? @Qualcuno thats strange it shouldnt .., I will test when I get a chance

Comment: Thanks, it works. and, yes jQ wraps some weird encoding since its parsed into stringify as an object. But it does what I want, so I'm not going to poke around anymore. I don't obviously don't know php :P